# Canvas image src from hosted file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

currently I am calling canvas source images from imgur, but I would like to host them within my app, like "images/soundwave.png"... .. given my current code, I cant figure out how to do that.

If it helps at all I am using Middleman

```
<script>
  var imgBg = new Image(),
      imgFg = new Image(),
      count = 2;
  imgBg.onload = imgFg.onload = init;
  imgBg.src = "http://i.imgur.com/hRHH9VO.png";
  imgFg.src = "http://i.imgur.com/WoJggN0.png";

  function init() {

     var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
         ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
         audio =  document.querySelector("audio");

    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 120;

    render();

    audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", render);

    function render() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


      // calc progress
      var progress = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;

      // draw clipped version of top image
      if (progress > 0) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgFg, 0, 0, imgFg.width * progress, imgFg.height,  // source
                             0, 0, canvas.width * progress, canvas.height); // dst
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source directory you can create an `images` folder and put the images in there.

Then, you can either set the image src to your app URL or a relative URI (e.g. `/images/hRHH9VO.png`).

Then, if you just need to embed an image in the page you can use the [image_tag](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/helper_methods/) template helper.

Comment: that worked but is there any alternative to "imgBg.src = "http://localhost:4567/images/soundwave_1_dark.png";" while you are working ... bc it is not live yet, .. so there is no real URL.... ?

Comment: I believe you can just set imgBg.src = "/images/soundwave_1_dark.png"